# How can I add text to my column's select statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to prepend text to sql select,

I can do this:

```
SELECT (1328724983-time)/60/60 AS status 
FROM voting 
WHERE account = 'ThElitEyeS' AND vid = 1
```

This will show time left.

What I'd like to do is this though:

```
SELECT 'Please try after' + (1328724983-time)/60/60 AS status 
FROM voting 
WHERE account = 'ThElitEyeS' AND vid = 1
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `cast` or `convert` to convert it all to `varchar` for instance.

```
SELECT 'Please try after' + CAST((1328724983-time)/60/60 as varchar(80)) AS status 
  FROM voting 
  WHERE account = 'ThElitEyeS' AND vid = 1;
```

[See the MSDN on Cast / Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Based on your comments you can do:

`SELECT 'Please try again after' + CAST(MyColForHours as varchar(25)) + ' hours', AnyOtherColumns FROM Table`

Comment: thanks works perfect. 
is there any way to put hours at end too ? :P

Comment: Like this Please try after 4 hours

Comment: @BahaaZahika just do as I said - read the docs I posted them as well.  I think what I posted should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks. In python I had a problem to casting and I solved it in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Was trying this today and getting an error

> SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".  SQLSTATE=22018

Apparently we now need to use || instead of + to join the sections.

> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448700

Comment: For a `DB2` database that may be true, but this question is directed at `SQL Server`